# phalcon php switches update to insert

Tags: php, phalcon

For some reason phalcon is replacing my order to an insert instead of an update (I can see that in the logs)

```
$phql = "UPDATE Vouchers SET user_name = :userName:, used = true WHERE voucher_code = :voucherCode:";
$status = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, array(
    'userName' => $voucherReq->userName,
    'voucherCode' => $voucherCode
));
```

I'm probably missing something overriding an update to an insert... well that's a lot. This is a special model that doesn't follow the common ID pattern (if it helps).

In the logs I can see:

```
[Mon Oct 13 23:49:49.698965 2014] [:error] [pid 379] [client 82.113.121.157:60949] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "voucher_voucher_code_idx"' in /var/www/api/index.php:41\nStack trace:\n
#0 [internal function]: PDOStatement->execute()\n
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Db\\Adapter\\Pdo->executePrepared(Object(PDOStatement), Array, Array)\n
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Db\\Adapter\\Pdo->execute('INSERT INTO "vo...', Array, Array)\n
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Db\\Adapter->insert('vouchers', Array, Array, Array)\n
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->_doLowInsert(Object(Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\MetaData\\Memory), Object(Phalcon\\Db\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Postgresql), 'vouchers', false)\n
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->save()\n
#6 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->update(Array)\n
#7 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Query->_executeUpdate(Array, Array, NULL)\n
#8 [internal function]: Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Query->execute(Array, NULL)\n
#9 /var/www/api/index.php(41): Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Manager->executeQue in /var/www/api/index.php on line 41
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you attache the log entries relating to this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I edited the question to include the logs.

Comment: `/var/www/api/index.php(39): Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model->save()` <--- that does not match to what you provided in the question

Comment: You're right, that was my second try. I've updated the new log.

Comment: maybe your update query fails and it tries to insert it?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: thanks for your input. I abandoned this but I'm gonna rate your solution because it makes sense for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've suffered from similar behavior.
Seems that Phalcon needs the update `where` clause to be on the primary key in order to update that specific row. I've added `id` as a primary key and all went OK.
In your case set `voucher_code` as primary key for that table.
Hope this helps